# Windows 10 does not recognize Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-leonardo, windows

Using Arduino Leonardo, IDE 1.8.9, Windows 10.

For a short time, when I first got the Leonardo, Windows 10 would recognize the board; I could see it in devices, Windows 10 would make a sound when plugged in, it would show listed in the ports of the IDE, and I could upload my code to the board (confirmed with blinking light sketch). ***It no longer does.***

The error I get in the IDE `avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding`.

I believe the main issues stems from I had selected Arduino UNO (I have a couple of those as well) in the IDE and Uploaded my sketch.

Ever since I did this, Windows 10 no longer recognizes the board when plugged in. It doesn't even show in "other devices" under device manager.

I have tried the following:

- The on-board reset trick that seems to be most of what other users experience and solves their issue. All variations. Holding the reset button, uploading, releasing, etc.
- Swapping cables. Confirmed with another device it was a data cable and working.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the IDE
- Restarting numerous times
- Burning boot loader - since Windows 10 won't recognize the device, this fails immediately can't even communicate to the board.

I have seen similar questions about this, but none of them seem to specifically cover what I am encountering.

Comment: did you try a double reset?

Comment: the bootloader can be burned only with a programmer so it is not relevant if the board shows up as a port

Comment: I believe so yes. reset.. click upload... reset again when IDE says uploading?

Comment: no reset and reset. then select port and upload

Comment: yes tried that as well. waiting for it to appear in the ports menu. never does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've bricked it.  Your broken sketch (wrong MCU selected) means that it's not presenting a CDC/ACM port.

Your best bet is to use a hardware programmer (eg USBASP or another Arduino) to erase the chip and reload the bootloader.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you point me to a tutorial for this?

Comment: @static_cast It's the same as burning any Arduino bootloader. There's millions of tutorials online about how to do it. TBH I'd buy a USBASP. They're dirt cheap from China.