# Arduino UNO not showing up in USB devices on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: serial, usb, icsp

I have an Arduino UNO (clone, not original) that was working fine until a couple of days ago. Now, it does not show up when I connect it to my laptop.

Things that I've troubleshouted:

1. USB cable is fine (tried with another Arduino).
2. USB ports are fine (tried with another Arduino).
3. Followed all the fixes and checks listed
   [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board?newreg=3f52658e2bbc4b77969435f443c1bccf)
   and everything is successful.
4. I can upload sketches trough ICSP using a working Arduino.
5. I've tailed `syslog` while connecting and disconnecting the failing
   Arduino and nothing shows up (it does when using the "good one").
6. I've tried on a Windows 10 machine and it doesn't show up.

What else can I try?

Comment: CH340 USB chip on it?

Comment: @Majenko Atmega16U2

Comment: Unusual. Maybe it's not a real one or its a factory reject. Probably dead. Continue using ICSP or use a USB UART dongle with it

Comment: Wondering if you bricked it similiar to my issue. @Majenko helped me as well :). Link to that answer located here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66239/windows-10-does-not-recognize-arduino-leonardo

Comment: @static_cast I see that your problem was solved by reuploading the bootloader. I've already try that and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet but have you updated your board manger for UNO on unbunto?

tools > Board > Board Manger > Search UNO

Kind of dumb to have to do that but it happen to me before and this was the solution I did.

Comment: It's already at the most recent version.